Vscode Vim balance/wrap parens
Given foo(a, b, c) please give me an efficient way to achieve
foo({a, b, c}).
Sorry, I could not find a suitable answer on StackOverflow.
Open to a vscode extension or a guide on how to achieve using Vscode vim.
I have seen the surround plugin but couldn't figure out how to do it with jumping into Visual mode.

can you not just go into insert mode, select the text, and then press open-curly-brace?

When on the desired paren in normal mode, try ci({}<Esc>P.

You're missing the closing curly brace. Try ci({}<Esc>P or (what I'd do) ci({<C-R>"}<Esc>.

You're right, depending on whether Vscode automatically closes the braces.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
